# spring 3.1 with hibernate 4 with spring security 3.1: How do I ensure that I have all the dependencis included and which tags to include?

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring mvc application with hibernate 4 and spring security 3.1. I am using maven as a dependency management tool.

How do I ensure that I have all the dependencies included? Is there a website where I can type in these framework names and it will generate the pom for me?

Attempt:

So I found out all the dependencies I need for Spring MVC and Hibernate 4.1. I am pasting it here for others just in case anyone else is looking for a similar thing. I will work on the spring security part now and update this post once I configure it successfully:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate-version>4.1.1.Final</hibernate-version>
    <mysql-version>5.1.20</mysql-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Used for Hibernate4 LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AOP dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Persistence Management -->
    <dependency> <!-- Apache BasicDataSource -->
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- Hibernate -->
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        <!-- will come with Hibernate core -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Is this not maven's raison d'etre?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you have to either:

- Do it the hard way, read each library's docs and figure out what maven dependencies it need (the problem doesn't end just by having all the required dependencies included, but you have to also make sure no dependencies conflicts. Eg: if you deploy the app to JBoss container, you need to consider what JBoss already provide & what you should / should not include)
- If above is too complicated, you can utilise spring roo -- at least for the initial setup. Spring roo will automatically adjust your pom so all the required dependencies is there. But you might not have the hibernate / spring security version you intended

My personal preference when deploying spring apps is to tomcat container, because it's almost plain blank and you have less chance of dealing with conflicts.

Comment: I found out all the repos for spring and hibernate till now. Thanks!